# Power amplifier circuit

Tags: power-amplifier

[image: PA]

In the power amplifier circuit shown if the input is an RF sine wave, with VDD=1.8V and Vgs = 1V, what will be the waveform at the drain of the MOSFET - sine or square wave? Is it possible to get a sine wave at the drain?

Comment: Quick answer: Sinewave. More precise answer: a distorted sinewave but nowhere anything close to a square wave. L1 and C1 form a resonant tank which will attenuate frequencies outside the passband so even though M1 can be pushing a squarewave shaped current into the tank, the resulting voltage will be much more sinusoidal. How much depends on the Q of the tank.

Comment: Get a sim and simulate.

Answer (score 1):

If the Rout of M1 is high, and Q of LC is high, you will build up the stored energy in that resonator, for a large sinusoid.